# MySQL Wordpress Issue - "Too many Connections repeat issue" and "WordPress Database Error Server Shutdown in Progress"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, server, cpanel

I am stuck in a weird issue.

My error log is filled with **"WordPress Database Error Server Shutdown in Progress"** and when I enabled WP_DEBUG in WordPress, it shows the attached error ie. **MySQL: Too Many connections.**
[image]

I have tried:

1. Restarting Apache
2. Restarting MySQL
3. Changing config files for both to accept more connections

Every time I restart and access the site, the MySQL process on the server overloads and takes almost 200% CPU and then hangs. This keeps repeating.
I tried a lot of solutions from the net, but no success.

*Note: I am using a Dedicated Server backed by Cpanel WHM.*

Please guide.

Regards
Saurabha J

Comment: Unfortunately this could be hard to track down. First make sure MySQL has enough resources for your usage, then figure out which queries are causing the server to hang.

Comment: We do have enough resources as everything was working fine till today morning. The issue is these are autogenerated default WP queries, so there is very little we can do about it.

Comment: first check the mysql error logs and see if you can access via phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

There could be MANY possible causes for this, but to help try and track things down, here are a few suggestions:

1. Whilst this is happening run a MySQL query: `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`
   This will show you what queries which are being run at that moment, along with all the MySQL connections open. You might need to run it several times in quick succession to get a good feel for queries during these peaks.
2. Check you aren't creating a persistent MySQL connection within your PHP script if you don't need it. With a typical PHP workload, you will want a MySQL connection to be closed at the end of each PHP script. Leaving the connections open/persisting can cause them to build up over time leading to max connection errors like you're reporting.
3. Enable/review your MySQL slow logs - any long-running queries will be seen here. Details on how to do so here; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

Not strictly related to the question, but your errors point out the use of legacy `mysql_` PHP functions, you really do want to look into upgrading these as soon as possible. If you're not sure which of MySQLi VS PDO, check out this guide; https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php